# Problem on using containers within models C#

Tags: c#, api, logic

I try to use models to get my containers on stored procedure executions , but it says that `SP` on `SP.GR0007R`, which is variable of the models, is a variable but used like a type, but if i use `Cont.ReportManager.GR0007R` instead, no errors found but no result either.

This is my code:

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    var param = new DynamicParameters();
    switch (filter.RPTCode)
    {
        case "GR0007R":
            param.Add("@Name", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.NAME) ? filter.NAME : string.Empty);
            var sp7r = await db.QueryAsync<SP.GR0007R>(filter.RPTQuery, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            break;
    }
    res = true;
}
```

this is where i declare SP

```
 public async Task<bool> GetReportData(Models.ReportManager.EswisReportModel SP, GetListParameterReportList filter)
```

and this is my model

```
 public class EswisReportModel
{
    public Cont.ReportManager.GR0001R GR0001R { get; set; }
    public Cont.ReportManager.GR0002R GR0002R { get; set; }
    public Cont.ReportManager.GR0007R GR0007R { get; set; }
    public Cont.ReportManager.GR0008R GR0008R { get; set; }
    public Cont.ReportManager.GR0009R GR0009R { get; set; }
}
```

so do i have to convert it or there's other way to call it?
thank you

Comment: could you please show your `filter.RPTCode`, `filter.NAME` and `filter.RPTQuery` which you are trying to pass to `GetReportData` method

Comment: 'public class GetListParameterReportList : PagedInputDto
    {
        public string RPTCode { get; set; }
        public string RPTQuery { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
    }'

Comment: I mean how do you call `GetReportData` this method and what values passed in `filter` paramter

Comment: it's an API logic, i call it on controller, and values that i use on RPTCode is "GR0007R", and could you show me how to use a textbox like thingy? ex: filter one, lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to put in an instance and property name, and hope that the generic handling will be so smart to know you mean the backing type of that property. It doesn't. According to the C# specification, you need to use the type name, not a reference to it, nor some kind of inferred use of it through a variable name.

So that is why you should use the actual type name, `Cont.ReportManager.GR0007R`:

```
var sp7r = await db.QueryAsync<Cont.ReportManager.GR0007R>(...);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Patrick, but like i said, i've tried it and no errors found but no result either

Comment: That it doesn't return any result can have a lot of reasons. Now the code just doesn't compile, so it proofs my answer fixes that issue and explains why it occurs.